# What exactly spine is in UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, ios7, uipageviewcontroller

The iOS doc says that we can present one or 2 pages at a time depending on the spine location or position and double sided state...
But, I am unable to understand "**What exactly spine is in UIPageViewController ?**"[image]

Comment: spine is in the central of two pages in this case.

Comment: Then What do we mean by spine location none, min, max, mid... Is that the separator b/w 2 pages... in that case using min and max will give more screen space to one page and less screen space to other

Comment: in Uipageview controller you can see that in landscape mode 2 child view controller seen. so when you rotate from potrait to landscape it needs 2 view controller. so the spine location delegate method handle this operation for 2 different controller.

Comment: @Anjan Please explain the second comment from top

Comment: The spine in a book is its binding. In your image it's in the middle. Min means the spine is on the left of the screen. Imagine then that you have a large book with the binding on the left of the iPad, and the pages turn from right to left as you go forward in your book.

Comment: Thanks! It will be nice for everyone if you post this as answer...

Answer (score 28):

It applies only when `transitionStyle` is set to `PageCurl` (otherwise it evaluates to `None`); during the animation of the `UIPageViewController` a 3D page is displayed: this property controls where the border of the page is attached with respect to the parent controller (that is, the position of the 'spine' of the displayed 3D book).

`Min` means it is attached on the left side, `Max` for the right, and `Mid` displays two consecutive pages split in the middle. In pictures (the spine is in red):

[image: Apple example PageViewController app with different spine settings]

Reference: [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation).